# UnitTest reports SQL error - cant find data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I use this code:

```
using (var unitOfWork = this.unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    var tagParam = new SqlParameter
                       {
                           ParameterName = "@tagList",
                           SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured,
                           Value = tags.ToTVP(),
                           TypeName = "[dbo].[TagList]"
                       };

    unitOfWork.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_InsertTagList @tagList", tagParam);
    // unitOfWork.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Tags SELECT Name FROM @tagList", tagParam);
}
```

`ToTvp` is just an extension method making a `DataTable` for me from a list of items.

I get this error:

> Test method InspiredBlog.UnitTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw
>   exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column, parameter, or
>   variable @tagList. : Cannot find data type dbo.TagList.

I have created the table type in the my database.

```
CREATE TYPE TagList AS TABLE 
(
    Name VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO
```

I don't know why this error is coming back!

I can easily create a SQL query and execute within SSMS

Comment: Is your type in database have dbo scope?

Comment: yes it does, dbo.TagList

Comment: Try to execute SP in SSMS with parameter value you are trying to pass from code.

Comment: Connect to database with profiler and look at query

Comment: @PareshJadhav i already can execute it within SSMS! i will look at the profiler

Comment: @gabba there is nothing going to SQL Profiler so this something that is complete C# side by the looks of it

Comment: if you correctly setup profiler params, looks like you connect to another database.

Comment: The profiler will catch all connections to my Database server, therefore I should see all connections!

Comment: Can you run a CommandType.StoredProcedure instead of a string of SQL?

Comment: Can you show what's your SP looks like? Following is the link on how to use table value parameters : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/